# Pass attribute to new page on link click. JS / jQuery

Tags: javascript, html

I have a button which directs someone to a new page. There is an Id on the button. Is there  a way for me to pass that Id to the next page? Preferably not in the URL. Can I do this through JS or jQuery without having to use AJAX?

And I would also like the click function to open a new tab as well.

```
            jQuery('<button class="btn"/>')
                .attr({'id': 'PASS_THIS'})
                .text('Button')
                .click(function() {
                     top.location.href = 'myNewPage.html';
                })
                .appendTo(btnspan)
```

Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> There is an Id on the button. Is there a way for me to pass that Id to the next page? Preferably not in the URL.

If you don't want to do it in the URL, you can use [`sessionStorage`](http://www.w3.org/TR/webstorage/#the-sessionstorage-attribute), which has [good browser support](http://caniuse.com/#feat=namevalue-storage) and is easy to use, or cookies if you need broader support. Save the `id` on click, then retrieve it in the new page.

Example with `sessionStorage` -- saving on click:

```
jQuery('<button class="btn"/>')
    .attr({
        'id': 'PASS_THIS'
    })
    .text('Button')
    .click(function () {
        sessionStorage.someUsefulNameHere = this.id; // <== Here
        top.location.href = 'myNewPage.html';
    })
    .appendTo(btnspan);
```

Retrieving it on the target page:

```
var someUsefulNameHere = sessionStorage.someUsefulNameHere;
```

and then optionally removing it so a refresh doesn't see it:

```
sessionStorage.removeItem("someUsefulNameHere");
```

Comment: Very helpful T.J. Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

May be this will be useful.

```
jQuery('<button class="btn"/>')
                .attr({'id': 'PASS_THIS'})
                .text('Button')
                .click(function() {
                     top.location.href = 'myNewPage.html?id='+jQuery(this).attr('id');
                })
                .appendTo(btnspan)
```

Comment: *"Preferably not in the URL."*

Comment: Separately: That would always pass `""` as the `id`. It wouldn't pass the `id` of the button that was clicked. The code `...?id='+jQuery('<button class="btn"/>').attr('id');` *creates* a new `button` element with no `id`, then gets the `id` from it and throws it away.

Comment: Re your edit fixing that: What exactly is wrong with `this.id`? Or if you're going to repeat the value of the `id` in a selector, just putting it directly in the URL rather that getting `"foo"` by doing `$("#foo").attr("id")`? That's just a really long way around...

Comment: yeah it can be passed also.